# Closed subspace of a compact topological space is compact

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, compactness, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a compact topological space, and $A$ a closed subspace. Show that $A$ is compact.

How does this look?

---

Proof:

In order to show that $A$ is compact. We need to show that for any open cover $U$ of $A$, it contains a finite open cover of $A$.

Let $U$ be a open cover of $A$.

For each $U_\alpha \in U$, there exists an open set $V_\alpha \in X$ so that $V_\alpha \cap A = U_\alpha$.

Here we denote the index set of $U$ by $I$, and $\alpha \in I$.

Now, set $V = \{V_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$, then $V \cap \{X \setminus U\}$ is an open cover of $X$.

It contains a finite subcover $\{V_1, ..., V_n\} \cup \{X \setminus U\}$ of $X$,

hence $\{ V_1 \cap A, ..., V_n \cap A \}$ is a finite subcover of $A$.

Hence $A$ is compact.

Comment: To be more rigorous, you could say by compactness, there exists a finite subset $F \subset I$ such that $\cup_{\alpha \in F}V_\alpha \cup (X \setminus A)$ is a cover for $X$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an excellent proof, with exactly the details needed.

Comment: @PandaMan: Only one thing to fix. Namely, you should have $\mathcal V\cup\{X\setminus A\}$ as your open cover of $X.$ You might also want to *prove* that $A$ is covered by $\{V_1\cap A,...,V_n\cap A\}.$

Comment: Good points, @Cameron. I was lulled into a false complacency. :)

Answer (score 0):

More concise:

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a compact topological space and let $A \subset X$ be closed and let $\{U_j\}$ be an open covering for $A$. Then as $A$ is closed, $X \setminus A$ is open and $\cup_{j \in J}U_j \bigcup X \setminus A$ covers $X$ which is compact so there exists a finite subset $I \subset J$ such that $\cup_{j \in I}U_j=A$ is a finite subcover of our arbitrary open covering making $A$ compact.