# Find a locally compact space $X$ with a subspace $A$ that is NOT locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, examples-counterexamples, topological-groups

I'd like to find a locally compact space $X$ with a subspace $A$ that is NOT locally compact.

As from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/698029/a-closed-subspace-of-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-is-also-a-locally-compact), I know that if $A$ is closed and $X$ is Hausdorff, then $A$ is locally compact.

Anyone have an example that satisfies the condition?

Comment: Try taking $X=\mathbb{R}^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$A=\mathbb Q\subset X=\mathbb R$$

Comment: this one is perfect, since I know how to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not locally compact. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Dear PandaMan, I'm glad the answer helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Take Cantor space $\{0,1\}^\omega$ as $\mathbf{X}$ (which is compact), and then note that the subspace $$\mathbf{Y} := \{p \in \{0,1\}^\omega \mid |\{i \in \mathbb{N} \mid p(i)=0\}| = \infty\}$$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, which is not locally compact.

Answer (score 1):

The subset $$A=(\Bbb R_{>0}\times\Bbb R)\cup\{(0,0)\}$$
of $\Bbb R^2$ is not locally compact, since $\Bbb R^2$ is Hausdorff but $A$ is not open in its closure $\overline A=\Bbb R_{\ge0}×\Bbb R$